# Implementing custom okhttp3.Callback

Tags: java, android, multithreading, okhttp

Generally, when I get a response back from okhttp3 Callback the code is successful and I process ui with the Response body.  This usually involves putting lines inside a `runOnUIThread()` or a `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(...)`.  To save on the tabbing hell this sometimes creates and to separate transport-layer codes into separate callbacks, can I do something like this?

```
public abstract class AbsCustomCallback implements okhtt3.Callback {

    @Override
    public abstract void onFailure(Call call, IOException e);

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        onSuccessMainThread(response);
                    } else {
                        onFailureCodeMainThread(response);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public abstract void onSuccessMainThread(Response response) throws IOException;

    public abstract void onFailureCodeMainThread(Response response) throws IOException;
}
```

Will this implementation always work?  This would force a new CustomCallback to implement onFailure, onSuccessMainThread, and onFailureCode callback methods.

Comment: What is "tabbing hell"?

Comment: "Tabbing hell" is just a bunch of nested callbacks, where you need to tab for a new block.  It doesn't look very pretty and is sometimes hard to read.  For example there's the okhttp callback and to do ui thread work you need to make a new handler, so there are already two levels of indentation for any http callback that does ui work.

Comment: I think it does if you added the onFailureCode inside the handler